# Newline operation for variables, find and grep

Tags: bash

I keep getting bitten over and over again with newline issues.

My first issue is, I have a string in bash where I'm appending "\n" via the echo -e command, because I want each result to be on it's own line, as I'm going to output that string eventually to file.  When I echo the string out, it looks correct.  If I grep through it trying to find one line,

```
var=$(echo $var2 | grep pattern)
```

I discover that it sees the string as one line.  I don't want that.  How do I change that so grep would work as expected, matching the lines of interest (question 1).

Also, if you have any insights on the following, seemingly related, I'd appreciate it:  when I do a find on the command line, it separates results by (apparently) newlines.  Assigning the results of find to a bash variable and then grepping or searching through that, it appears the find results are all one line.  I've tried/researched some of the

```
find -print
```

options but haven't been successful, perhaps it is a similar problem to number 1.   I'm not getting something here.  The second question would be, what's the right option to use on a find command so when I assign it to a variable and grep through the results, it works like it would on the command line (meaning find | grep).

Thanks.

Comment: Can you include a reproducer? Without one, it's not clear what you mean.

Comment: I strongly suspect that somewhere, you're doing an `echo $string` rather than a `echo "$string"`.

Comment: ...also, don't use `echo -e`. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html, particularly APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections: The POSIX specification for `echo` doesn't allow an implementation passed `-e` to do anything but print that `-e` on its output; thus, you're explicitly relying on having an implementation that breaks the standard.

Comment: Charles, you were right.  I had a var=$(echo $var2 | grep pattern).  I left off the quotes.

Comment: Consider `var=$(grep pattern <<<"$var2")` instead, btw. No need for a pipeline there.

Comment: Also, I strongly advise against using `find -print` programatically -- keep in mind that newlines are valid characters inside filenames, so you can't safely use them to *separate* filenames.

Comment: Ok.  Per the "if you must", should I not use grep?

Comment: Depends on the context. Grep is often an appropriate tool.

Comment: ...on the other hand, grepping the output of `find` is often evil.

Comment: Thanks.   What's a print option on find, that when assigned to a bash variable, it's going to properly get newlines in the bash variable?  Just for those odd cases.

Comment: Well, that's the thing -- you don't *want* newlines in the bash variable unless the filename itself contains newlines. Instead, you should use NUL-delimited output, and load content into an array.

Comment: And then what do I use to search the array (vs) grep, and say feed (pipe) the result into some other command?

Comment: `files=( ); while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do files+=( "$filename" ); done < <(find . -print0)` gives you an array called `files`, which you can then print unambiguously with `printf '%q\n' "${files[@]}"`, enumerate the size of with `echo "Found ${#files[@]} files"`, or whatnot.

Comment: If you want to search through the list of filenames, you should be telling `find` to filter it. It's very, very flexible on that count.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87323/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-ray).

Comment: I want all the files.   I just need to do different operations on the results that I don't want to do in an exec (for now).

Comment: Can't, my company firewall won't allow a chat.

Comment: So, if I can, if I put the results into an array, how do I find "abc" in that array and pipe the result to some other command?  Thanks for your help BTW.

Comment: If you're trying to find something in the array, you should have been telling `find` to filter it earlier.

Comment: Maybe that means you should have used `-name '*abc*'`, or `-regex '.*abc.*'`.

Comment: I want broad find results to do one thing, and then further filter the results and do other things.

Comment: Can't give good situational advice based on broad descriptions. Details always matter.

Comment: That said, you can emit an array as a NUL-delimited stream again with `printf '%s\0' "${array[@]}"`, and filter through that list with `grep -z` (if you're on a platform with GNU tools).

Comment: ...modern systems will generally have tools that can deal with NUL-delimited streams (grep -z, xargs -0, find -print0, etc); failing to cover this was one of the bigger design failures in the POSIX spec.

Comment: Thanks, (again, I know general), is grep a good/efficient tool to use to find a pattern in a bash array (as you showed), or should I use a bash array search mechanism and pass that on?

Comment: ...and of course you can iterate through and filter bash arrays in native bash as well.

Comment: It's all situational. If you're going to be doing lots of searches for specific item rather than a substring, the right thing to do is to load your items as keys in an associative array (what other languages might call a hash or a map), so your lookups for them are O(1).

Comment: Suggest you might consider starting with http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005, by the way.

Comment: Thanks Charles, I see.  Often I need to find substrings, so thanks for differentiating that and what to read.

Comment: Usually, though, I tend to avoid storing such lists at all -- iterating over contents in realtime (see FAQ 1) is considerably more memory efficient than storing for later processing.

Comment: ...and it's easy to do pattern matches during real-time processing: `while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do case $filename in *abc*) : "do something";; *def*) : "do something else";; esac; done < <(find . -print0)`

Comment: Thank you.  I need to make more time to study Bash rather than just trying to get the job done as fast as possible.   I appreciate your support.